# Переменная String не сохраняет в себя значения (С#)

Tags: c#, строки

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Uchenik
{
    public string imya;
    public string familia;
    public string klass;
}
    class Program   
    {
        static Uchenik GetUchenik()
        {
            Uchenik uchenik = new Uchenik();
            
            uchenik.imya = "Вася";
            uchenik.familia = "Пупкин";
            uchenik.klass = "Второй б";
            
            return uchenik;
        }
        static void Print(Uchenik uchenik)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Имя ученика");
            Console.WriteLine("Фамилия ученика");
            Console.WriteLine("Класс ученика"); 
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var PerviyUchenik = GetUchenik();
        
            Print (PerviyUchenik);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Подумайте просто логически, что делает метод `Print()` у вас. Вот вы передали ему объект, ок, а выводить его значения? Или думаете C# такой умный, что поймет, что здесь ``Console.WriteLine("Имя ученика");` нужно выводить именно имя за вас? Ошибаетесь, это просто вывод текста "Имя ученика" на экран, не более, а само имя в переменной `uchenik` (`uchenik.imya`). И да, ужасные наименования, если учитесь, то учитесь сразу правильно, привыкайте писать на английском, по всем правилам именования!

Comment: @user505121, какой способ (НИЖЕ ПРИВЕДЕНЫ) вам понравился ? Через свойство или конструктор с параметрами ?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы чуток подправил вашу реализацию.

Хотелось-бы отметить - не используйте транслит или написание английских слов на русском в названиях. Это крайне важно для того, чтобы увеличить понимание кода другими программистами. Да и выглядит это гораздо приятнее.

[Соглашение о написании кода на C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions)

Для начала, используйте свойства и конструкторы класса. Так же, не забывайте об использовании модификаторов доступа. Например, если сделать `public string Name { get; private set; }`, то установить значение можно только внутри самого класса Student. Извне это можно будет сделать с помощью методов.

```
internal class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Class { get; set; }

    public Student() { }

    public Student(string name, string surname, string @class)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Class = @class;
    }
}
```

[Свойства](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.4.php) [Классы](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.1.php) [Конструкторы](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.35.php)

Далее метод создания студента. Так как выше мы создали 2 конструктора, то мы можем воспользоваться следующей записью:

```
static Student CreateStudent()
{
    //благодаря нашему кастомному конструктору
    var student = new Student("Вася", "Пупкин", "Второй б");
    //или по дефолтному конструктору
    var student2 = new Student()
    {
        Name = "Вася",
        Surname = "Пупкин",
        Class = "Второй б"
    };
    //аналогичной является запись. Просто запись выше чуть короче
    var student3 = new Student();
    student3.Name = "Вася";
    student3.Surname = "Пупкин";
    student3.Class = "Второй б";
    //И возвращаем студента. Они все одинаковые, Поэтому нет разницы, какого возвращать
    return student;
}
```

Печать. Есть несколько способов. Это лишь парочка из них. Так же есть `string.Format`, `string.Join`, `StringBuilder` и многие-многие другие:

```
static void Print(Student student)
{
    //несколько способов
    Console.WriteLine($"Имя ученика {student.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine("Фамилия ученика " + student.Surname);
    Console.WriteLine(@"Класс ученика {0}", student.Class);
}
```

[Операции со строками](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.2.php)

Но мы можем пойти чуть дальше и не создавать этот метод `Print`. Возвращаемся в класс `Student` и добавляем переопределение метода `ToString`.

```
internal class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Class { get; set; }

    public Student() { }

    public Student(string name, string surname, string @class)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Class = @class;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //"\n" переносит на другую строку
        return $"Имя студента {Name}\n" +
            $"Фамилия студента {Surname}\n" +
            $"Класс {Class}";
    }
}
```

[Переопределение](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.42.php)

Таким образом, мы можем сделать следующее:

```
var student = CreateStudent();
Console.WriteLine(student.ToString());
```

Но этот способ чуть сложнее.

Comment: Ключевое слово Class лучше не использовать. Хоть оно и с большой буквы.

Comment: @c0ol Я знаю об этом, но, если я сейчас ещё и об этом напишу, то тут явно одного ответа не хватит, т.к. тема нейминга довольно-таки большая. Вообще, хорошим тоном было-бы добавить ссылку на соглашение о написании кода майков. Сейчас отредактирую ответ. Спасибо

Comment: Да не, мелочь)))

Answer (score 2):

Переменная сохраняет, вы при выводе не просите это значение показывать :)

```
static void Print(Uchenik uchenik)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Имя ученика     " + uchenik.imya);
    Console.WriteLine("Фамилия ученика " + uchenik.familia);
    Console.WriteLine("Класс ученика   " + uchenik.klass); 
}
```

Comment: У меня же ниже 
```static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var PerviyUchenik = GetUchenik();

            Print(PerviyUchenik);
        }```

Comment: Вы не просите показывать `uchenik.imya` и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{

    class Person
    {
        public string name;
        public string surname; 
        public int education;


        public Person(){}

        public Person(string name, string surname, int education)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.education = education;
        }


        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;    // возвращаем значение свойства
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;   // устанавливаем новое значение свойства
            }
        }

        public string Surname
        {
            get
            {
                return surname;    
            }
            set
            {
                surname = value;   
            }
        }

        public int Education
        {
            get
            {
                return education;    
            }
            set
            {
                education = value;   
            }
        }


        public void Print() => Console.WriteLine($"Name: {name} Surname: {surname} Education: {education}");

    }


    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Person person = new Person();
            person.Name = "Vasa";
            person.Surname = "Pupkin";
            person.Education = 2;
            person.Print();

            // Можно изменить свойство - Вася перешел в 3-й класс !
            person.Education = 3;
            person.Print();

            // Передать в конструктор с параметрами
            Person john = new Person("John", "Petrov", 5);
            john.Print();

        }
    }
}
```

Простое описание для нашего дорогого студента:

1. Использование свойств;
2. Использование конструктора с параметрами.

Для печати тогда делаем так (в методе Main() ), а Print() для очистки совести:) не используем:

```
// Получаем значение свойства и присваиваем его переменной
string personName = person.Name;
Console.WriteLine(personName);  // Имя
```

Comment: Плохой пример печати. Класс НЕ должен печатать себя. Класс - описание какой-то сущности. Есть принципы SOLID, которые нужно соблюдать для поддержания качества кода на достойном уровне. Печатью могут заниматься контроллеры и прочие другие, но никак не сам же класс

Comment: Печать ТОЛЬКО для понимания опять же принципа. Не понял наш студент работу с объектами. А так вся печать в конце.

Comment: Я бы делал тогда отдельный вывод наших свойств, которые могут меняться в процессе правки.

Comment: Да, тут с вами соглашусь - код иногда дорабатывается и изменяется, но не стоит забывать и о том, что в процессе доработок, изменяют и сам вывод свойств. В конце-концов, если хотите создать уникальный метод, который никогда не нужно будет дорабатывать, существует рефлексия и дженерики. Можно использовать `typeof(T).GetProperties()`, откуда можно получить и название свойства, и его значение. Так же, существует переопределение методов. Пример: переопределяем метод `ToString`, в котором возвращаем всегда строку...

Comment: ...Таким образом, при добавлении нового свойства, нам нужно будет лишь чуток подправить метод `ToString` в конкретном классе. Реализация вывода где-то вне этого классе не изменится. Нужно будет всего лишь `*someClass*.ToString()`

Comment: Вывод в консоль по сути нужен только для проверки-отладки. Для вывода в окна реальной программы у нас уже есть все свойства и методы. А там снова свои компоненты. ИЛИ просто для понимания принципа работы в черновик - полезное дело !

Comment: Абсолютно с вами не согласен. Переопределение того же метода `ToString` позволяет, например, логировать данные. Не всегда классы можно сериализовать, поэтому пользуются созданием виртуальных методов, которые переопределяют в наследниках и выводят полученный json в ту же консоль или текстовый файл. И это только один пример, для чего можно использовать такую реализацию. Ещё пример: у вас есть Exception, который при вызове `throw` выводит свойство `Message`...

Comment: ...Оно имеет только геттер, поэтому пользуются переопределением метода `ToString` и `Message`. Получается следующая конструкция `override string Message => ToString()`. Либо созданием приватного поля `string _message`, в который записывают данные. Вариантов ещё много, зачем это можно использовать. Так или иначе, не вижу смысла продолжать эту бессмысленную дискуссию. Если вы считаете, что такой подход является правильным - не смею вас переубеждать

Comment: Согласен, зависит от конкретной решаемой задачи. Спасибо !

Comment: Метод `ToString` предназначен для отладки, он для программиста, а не для клиента. Делать ли в классе методы наподобие `Print` - это старый холивар anemic vs rich model. Оба подхода имеют свои плюсы и минусы. @Frehzy